# Github action workflow to generate Maven Release and deploy it, and then generate Snapshot to work locally?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, deployment, artifactory, release

I'm new in this devops world.
I'm building a Java SprinBoot API with maven. I'm building my yml file to develop the worfklow so when I push a change in my main branch then the workflow can execute and deploy a new release version in my Artifactory repository.

I want to deploy a new Release version in artifactory, but also change my local pom.xml project version to a SNAPSHOT at the sime time. Here is the part of my workflow where I create the Snapshot version and then the deploy, I know is not complete, but I don't know how to do the 2 steps.

```
  - name: Increment Version
    run: |
      chmod +x mvnw
      ./mvnw build-helper:parse-version versions:set -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.nextMinorVersion}.0-SNAPSHOT versions:commit
      git config user.name "GitHub Action"
      git config user.email "action@github.com"
      git add .
      git commit -m "updated version in pom.xml"
      git push

  - name: Create Git Tag
    run: |
      export version=$(./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout)
      git config user.name "GitHub Action"
      git config user.email "action@github.com"
      git tag -a $version -m "$version"
      git push origin $version

  - name: Deploy release to artifactory
    run: |
      echo ${{ secrets.SETTINGS_XML }} ~/.m2/settings.xml
      mvn deploy
```

Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to deploy a new Release version in artifactory, but also change my local pom.xml project version to a SNAPSHOT at the sime time

that is exactly what `maven-release-plugin` actually performs. You have two options:

1. use [Java Maven release](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/java-maven-release) github action
2. learn how `maven-release-plugin` is doing that ([prepare](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html), [perform](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html)) and try to reproduce that